# I want to sort channels out under the category, how to move it? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to move the 2 newly created text and voice channels under the newly created category

```
@bot.command()
async def room(ctx, name):
    guild = ctx.guild
    member = ctx.author
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        
    }
    channel = await guild.create_category_channel(name, overwrites=overwrites)
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name, overwrites=overwrites)
    channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(name, overwrites=overwrites)
    channel = ctx.channel
    name = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.category, name)
    await ctx.channel.edit(category=name)
```

[image: img]

Like this
How can I move two channels (chat, voice) below the category?

```
name = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.category, name)
await ctx.channel.edit(category=name)
```

This code is not working

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to move the 2 newly created text and voice channels under the newly created category? Also, do you get any errors? If so, please make sure you edit your question to share them. The reason `utils.get` is not working is because it requires an iterable to be passed such as [`ctx.guild.categories`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.categories)

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def room(ctx, roomname):
    guild = ctx.guild
    member = ctx.author
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        
    }
    channel = await guild.create_category_channel(roomname, overwrites=overwrites)
    text_channel = await guild.create_text_channel(roomname, category=channel, overwrites=overwrites)
    voice_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(roomname, category=channel, overwrites=overwrites)
```

I just entered the `category=channel` assignment in the channel parameter
then solved it.